# Is a mapping f bijection ?

Tags: general-topology

If Y is an one point compactification of X,Y=X union {p}, p not belong to X. Is a mapping f from X into Y bijection? If it is not, what are the assumptions I add to be f bijection ? Thanks for any help

Comment: The canonical mapping $X\hookrightarrow X\cup\{p\}=Y$ is an embedding, but it's not a bijection, as it clearly doesn't meet $p$

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what exactly you're asking.  If you're talking about the standard map $X \to X \cup \{p\}$ which sends $x \in X$ to $x \in X \cup \{p\}$ then no, this is not a bijection because $p$ is not in the image.  There are no conditions you can put on $X$ that cause this to be a bijection because by definition $p$ is always an *additional* element.

If you're asking whether there exists a bijection $X \to Y$.  This will be true whenever $X$ is infinite.  But this bijection, as we have seen, is **not** the standard map $X \to Y$ and in general need not have anything to do with the topology; it's likely not continuous.